Is it possible to store real world data on Hyperledger Fabric? for example a pdf file of healthcare data
Is it possible to store real world data on Hyperledger Fabric? for example a pdf file of healthcare data. If it is possible then can you give a brief idea about how to get started with it?
I have alread set up the test network configuration

It is possible to store whatever data you want on a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain. A smart contract is used to store and retrieve arbitrary binary data associated with ledger keys. For details of how a smart contract is implemented, look at this tutorial and the working asset-transfer-basic sample that it refers to.
While it is technically possible to store PDF files containing healthcare data, you should seriously consider both the size and sensitivity of the data. Blockchain is not optimised for storing large volumes of data. Data on the main ledger is also visible to anyone with access to the blockchain, and is immutable, meaning that it remains on the blockchain, even if those ledger keys are later overwritten or deleted. This might make it a bad fit for healthcare data, which likely needs to be kept private and might be subject to regulatory requirements to remove data.
If you have a use-case for which a blockchain is a good fit, but also involves storing large or sensitive data, you might consider storing data in some off-chain data store and just recording a hash of that data on the blockchain as proof that the off-chain data matches what is referred to on the blockchain. Another option that can be useful for some use-cases is to store data in Hyperledger Fabric's private data collections.
